# in bubble sort how do i implement if the value changed its position then change/assign the previous text name to change its position also

Tags: c

I have a [text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqj0f.jpg) where it contains all the data i need then i will read the data and do a bubble sort for Total Vaccines available and using bubble sort i arranged it in descending order but i need help with how to change the Vaccine_Code according the newly arranged Total_Vaccines. Please Help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct dist
{
char Name_Vaccine[5][15];
char Vaccine_Code[5][10];
char Producing_Country[5][15];
int Dosage_Required[5];
float Population_Covered[5];
float Total_Vaccines[5];
char distcode[100][100];
float distvalue[100];
};

int main()
{
struct dist sort[20];
int i, j, n=5,m;
float a,b;
FILE *f = fopen("vaccine.txt", "r");
FILE *fp = fopen("dist.txt","r");

//For Vaccine.txt
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    fscanf(f,"%s",sort->Name_Vaccine[i]);
    fscanf(f,"%s",sort->Vaccine_Code[i]);
    fscanf(f,"%s",sort->Producing_Country[i]);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&sort->Dosage_Required[i]);
    fscanf(f,"%f",&sort->Population_Covered[i]);
    fscanf(f,"%f",&sort->Total_Vaccines[i]);
}
fclose(f);

//Original Order
printf("The numbers arranged in Original order for Vaccine.txt are given below\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
{
    printf("%s %.4f\n",sort->Vaccine_Code[i], sort->Total_Vaccines[i]);
}

//  sorting begins ... //
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) 
    {
        if (sort->Total_Vaccines[i] < sort->Total_Vaccines[j]) 
        {
            a = sort->Total_Vaccines[i];
            sort->Total_Vaccines[i] = sort->Total_Vaccines[j];
            sort->Total_Vaccines[j] = a;
            
        }
    }
}
printf("The numbers arranged in Descending order for Vaccine are given below\n");

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
{
    printf("%s %9.4f\n",sort->Vaccine_Code[i], sort->Total_Vaccines[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of text but post text as properly formatted text in the question. You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of moving your data it's probably better to just move pointers to your data. Basically you initialize an array of size `n` with the numbers `0, ..., n - 1`. Then you sort the array using the comparison function that compares the values behind the index.

It should look something like the modified code below. But beware, I didn't test it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 5

struct dist
{
    char Name_Vaccine[5][15];
    char Vaccine_Code[5][10];
    char Producing_Country[5][15];
    int Dosage_Required[5];
    float Population_Covered[5];
    float Total_Vaccines[5];
    char distcode[100][100];
    float distvalue[100];
};

int main()
{
    struct dist sort[20];
    int i, j, n=ARRAYSIZE,m;
    int idxArray[ARRAYSIZE];
    float a,b;
    FILE *f = fopen("vaccine.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp = fopen("dist.txt","r");

    //For Vaccine.txt
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        fscanf(f,"%s",sort->Name_Vaccine[i]);
        fscanf(f,"%s",sort->Vaccine_Code[i]);
        fscanf(f,"%s",sort->Producing_Country[i]);
        fscanf(f,"%d",&sort->Dosage_Required[i]);
        fscanf(f,"%f",&sort->Population_Covered[i]);
        fscanf(f,"%f",&sort->Total_Vaccines[i]);
        idxArray[i] = i; // piggyback initialization of the index array
    }
    fclose(f);

    //Original Order
    printf("The numbers arranged in Original order for Vaccine.txt are given below\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%s %.4f\n",sort->Vaccine_Code[i], sort->Total_Vaccines[i]);
    }

    //  sorting begins ... //
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (sort->Total_Vaccines[idxArray[i]] < sort->Total_Vaccines[idxArray[j]]) {
                a = idxArray[i];
                idxArray[i] = idxArray[j];
                idxArray[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The numbers arranged in Descending order for Vaccine are given below\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%s %9.4f\n",sort->Vaccine_Code[idxArray[i]], sort->Total_Vaccines[idxArray[i]]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, with an array size of 5 the exact method doesn't play that much of a role. It would even be acceptable to search for the smallest element, greater than the last written element, for each line printed in the last loop.

Comment: First of thank of so much for your solution it is working thanks for saving my day.
i have implemented your idea to my other problem but I'm getting an error the output is not in descending order i tried fixing but i cannot find what's the problem. please once check this link. in that link check for dist.txt code
https://pastebin.com/kcKntvYF

Comment: Usually you only have to change the comparison operator from `<` to `>` in `sort->Total_Vaccines[idxArray[i]] < sort->Total_Vaccines[idxArray[j]]`

Comment: please once open this link because i already did that, there is something wrong other than changing operator pastebin.com/kcKntvYF

Comment: I'd be happy to test it. But I'd need one or two input files to do that but didn't find them on the linked page. Did I miss something?

Comment: thank you so much. here are the text files for that code
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/46b6a7cd7a4d608e0469afa3ded66c0620210630100151/0ed848

Comment: Thank you. And sorry, it was my fault. Instead of `for (j = idxArray[i + 1]; j < n; ++j)` it should be `for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)`. Sorry for that

Comment: no problem thank you so much for helping me out. now everything is working perfect.